# How to add jar of a project to the jar of another project during the build process

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have two projects X and Y. I want to add the jar of project X to jar of project Y during the build process of project Y. X and Y are both maven projects.

What's the correct way to add the jar to another jar(not as a dependency)?

Right now I am using this :

```
    <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>example.demo.project</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>X</artifactId>
                                    <version>1.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                    <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                    <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                            <!-- other configurations here -->
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Can you describe where the jar of X shoud be in the other JAR? should it be daflated (creating a fat-Jar with the sources of Y) or do you want the the jar X being somewhere within the Y.jar like in /libs/X.jar

Comment: JAR X should be in the rot directory of JAR Y. Like target/X.jar

Comment: Additional question, what do you like to achieve doing so? is that a runtime dependency? do you want to read the x jar from your code? do you want to have a jar that you can run using `java -jar Y.jar`?

Comment: Should this be an executable jar?

Comment: Yes, it has runtime dependency and on server it needs to be packaged with the Y JAR

Comment: So, how is it run on the server?

Comment: It is planned to be deployed on weblogic server and the jar X would interface with other applications

Comment: This seems like the wrong approach. Either you build a proper WAR or EAR to be deployed on an Application Server, or you build a runnable JAR to be run standalone.

Comment: I agree with you, since we are using EJB's which doesnt support call by reference, it must be given at run time. Let me know if there is any way we can package jar X into jar Y?